# Checking if a bundle exists (.app) using CoreFoundation in C

Tags: c, macos, core-foundation

I have application written in C. As part of what it does it needs to check that another app (a cocoa based .app application) is located in the right directory.

Of course using standard C I don't find the app because to C it is a *directory*. Is there any CoreFoundation function that will allow me to check if the app exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-123785) has some CoreFoundation samples for accessing a bundle, and then getting info (like the bundle identifier) out of it.

Alternately, if you need to search the whole system for a given bundle, you could probably use the Spotlight/MD functions to search for it.

Comment: I checked that page as well as the [CFBundle Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html) and I can't find anything that will tell me whether the app exists in a certain location. the closest was `CFBundleCopyResourceURLInDirectory` but it's not what I am looking for. I need a "FileExists(filename)" function that will work with a bundle. in C.

Comment: Does this work?: run `CFBundleCreate()` on the path where you expect the bundle to be. If it returns NULL, the bundle doesn't exist there. If it's a valid object, you know it exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you just care whether "some directory called something.app exists at a given place," then you can just use `fstat()` to make sure it exists and that it's a directory.

If you want something a bit fancier, then you can use `LSFindApplicationForInfo()` to request the `FSRef` or `CFURLRef` of a given bundle ID. You can then verify that the returned path is what you want.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it clearly enough. I *know* where the file should be located, I just want to check that it is there. All the examples for `LSFindApplicationForInfo` are telling me that this function will find an app based on an ID or other resources and return the path. I don't need that, I just need to check whether an app is located in the directory that is supposed to be.

Comment: When `LSFindApplicationForInfo` returns the path, you can then see if that path matches what you expect. If you just care "is this directory at this place" then you can use `fstat().`

Comment: fstat() will return true to a directory called application.app, that doesn't mean that `application.app` is there. Beside I don't know what application ID to use. I didn't write that app, it's a 3rd party app some of our developers use to support ours. So, isn't there a `if (FILE * file = fopen(filename, "r"))` but for a bundle that will tell me whether that file exits or not?

Comment: A bundle is not a file. A bundle is a directory. You can ask LaunchServices for the "app" (look in its Info.plist to find its identifier), or you can look in the file system for files and directories. There is no file system construct called a "bundle" so you can't ask the file system about them. If you're nervous about there being an .app directory that isn't an app, you can fstat() `<app>.app/Contents/Info.plist`. If that's there, it's definitely an application. But the best thing that will tell you if the "application" exists is LaunchServices, and then you can check its path.